# Retry Mechanism Not Actually Triggering the HTTP Call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following piece of code:

```
    const http$: Observable<Course[]> = this.http.request('/api/courses');

    const courses$ = http$
        .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('HTTP request invoked ...')),
            map( res => res['payload'] ),
            shareReplay(),
            retryWhen(errors =>
                errors.pipe(
                    tap(() => console.log('Error retry invoked ...')),
                    delayWhen(() => timer(2000)
                )
            )),
            retry(4)
        );
```

Now, when network failure happened, I checked the console and found the message 'Error retry invoked ...', but when I check the network tab, I cannot find the actual HTTP request invoked again.

Any reason behind this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe shareReplay is the problem here, try to remove it and test

Answer (score 1):

When you use `retryWhen` you don't have to add `retry(4)` , also remove the `shareReplay()` you should be able to see it retrying.

```
const courses$ = http$
    .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('HTTP request invoked ...')),
        map( res => res['payload'] ),
        retryWhen(errors =>
            errors.pipe(
                tap(() => console.log('Error retry invoked ...')),
                delayWhen(() => timer(2000)
            )
        )),
    );
```

Comment: Still same issue honestly. Logging only without the actual HTTP call.

Comment: in theory it should just work as expected, can u set up a simple codesandbox to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Found the problem with the http$ observable, I was setting up a controller with signal to close the connection automatically when it fails, this is why it was not retrying, fixed now. Thanks.